# Django equivalent of ASP.NET Parameter Binding or Ruby on Rails Action Controller Parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm wondering what's mentioned in the title. This are links to the examples mentioned, regarding other techs:

- [ASP.NET Parameter Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)
- [Ruby on Rails Action Controller
  Parameters](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html)

Currently I'm building an API using [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and using custom code in views or serializers validate methods to validate parameters, like this:

```
class AnimalWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_dicose_category(self, value):
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Dicose Category cannot be set manually.')
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in your example you are telling the serializer to support *`__all__`* fields, then you need to disable updating that one manually.

You probably mean to use use `exclude` as in the example below, which will simply remove the field from "all". The primary difference between `exclude` and using `read_only` is that the output will include the `dicose_category`.

---

Use the [`exclude=`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include) to exclude this field.  This is the opposite of `fields=`, and you can only use one at a time.

```
class AnimalWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dicose_category = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        exclude = ["dicose_category"]
```

You can declare the field as read only (directly or using [extra kwarg](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments)).  You can't write it but it will include be in the output.  I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but it can be helpful if you are using the return data for something and need it there.

```
class AnimalWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dicose_category = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = "__all__"

# or declare an extra_kwarg which does the same thing:
class AnimalWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {
            "dicose_category": { "read_only": True }
        }
```

And lastly, I strongly suggest listing all the fields you intended to be updated directly, rather than using `__all__` or `exclude=`.

1. New fields added to the model are not automatically updateable
2. All updateable fields are **explicitly** and clearly listed
3. Unit tests can now be explicit, and the output format is consistent

```
class AnimalWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = [
            "name",
            "mission",
            "favorite_color",
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks @andrew! this seems to improve what I already have, but then, there is no such a functionality that excludes unwanted parameters in the view? Like RoR and .NET do?

Comment: Can you give an example of "excluding unwanted parameters" to clear things up, a more concrete one?  Your question covers more than one area, and while I do have experience with net core mvc I don't see how it is different - you also have to explicitly include/exclude params on your models or in your path/qs.  This leads me to believe you are actually asking a different, deeper question and I am missing it.